# After reinstalling Linux on dual Boot, I have multiple boot options

Tags: dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I have a Lenovo Yoga c940 with eOS dual boot. I cleared the eOS partition using Windows disk management tool and reinstalled eOS on the empty space. I want to do it one more time (for reasons that are not important). However, during boot now, I have multiple instances of Linux boot hard drive (with the same ID). Is there a way to clear the Linux partition, delete all options except windows, so that I can reinstall eOS and have only 2 options, Win and eOS?

[image: Laptop Boot menu during boot]

[image: Gparted partitions]

Comment: You may not need to remove and reinstall eOS. This may be something relatively simple. Can you update your question to show a list of all storage devices and their partitions? This will make it easier to outline the next steps 

Comment: Thank you for the comment Matigo. Actually I want to reinstall eOS anyway. I made a mistake during partitioning and the root folder is now full. 
But now I am afraid that if I clear the Linux partitions with Windows Disk utilty and resize again, I will have 3 Ubuntu UEFI options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `$ update-grub2` or `$ update-initramfs -u`?

Comment: I dont think this will work unless you delete the windows partitions first ... the -u (update) looks for partitions to include for the boot

Answer (score 0):

U can use efibootmgr command to clear the unnecessary entries in your bios :

https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/efibootmgr

for usage